# How can I make calculator expressions with ", "(thousandth separator)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

guys. I am a new SwiftUI developer and have a question. I am currently working on a calculator that supports multi-step calculations.

I want to be able to support the display of ", "(thousandth separator) for numbers in expressions(the expressions is a string), such as:

So far done:
10000+20000-10000

Hope to achieve the following:
10,000+20,000-10,000

Thanks.

[image: calculator]

So far done:
10000+20000-10000

Hope to achieve the following:
10,000+20,000-10,000

Comment: When you write “expressions” do you mean NSExpression or is it about just string formatting? Please share your code that is relevant to the question.

Comment: Hi @Joakim Danielson, Thanks for your concern, it is about just string formatting, the "expressions" here just display the input itself, I will calculate the result somewhere else.

Comment: Fine but you need to add the relevant code to the question

Answer (score -1):

if you want to achieve the desired functionality of displaying numbers with thousand separators in your SwiftUI calculator app, you can use the NumberFormatter class provided by Foundation framework.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var expression = "10000+20000-10000"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(formatExpression(expression))
                .font(.title)
                .padding()
            
            // Other calculator UI components...
        }
    }
    
    private func formatExpression(_ expression: String) -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        
        let components = expression.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+-*/"))
        var formattedExpression = expression
        
        for component in components {
            if let number = formatter.number(from: component) {
                let formattedNumber = formatter.string(from: number) ?? ""
                formattedExpression = formattedExpression.replacingOccurrences(of: component, with: formattedNumber)
            }
        }
        
        return formattedExpression
    }
}
```

---

To display decimal numbers correctly in your expression, you can modify the `formatExpression` function to handle decimal points and trailing zeros. THe example:

```
private func formatExpression(_ expression: String) -> String {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 10  // Set the desired maximum fraction digits
    
    let components = expression.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+-*/"))
    var formattedExpression = expression
    
    for component in components {
        if let number = formatter.number(from: component) {
            let formattedNumber = formatter.string(from: number) ?? ""
            formattedExpression = formattedExpression.replacingOccurrences(of: component, with: formattedNumber)
        }
    }
    
    return formattedExpression
}
```

Input: `123.` -> Output: `123.`

Input: `123.0` -> Output: `123.0`

Input: `123.45` -> Output: `123.45`

---

Let me know if it helps. If so, please **leave your opinions** by **voting**!! ^^

Comment: Thanks for your reply @traizooo, I would like to say that your code works fine in most cases. It's just that when I start typing a decimal point, there is a little problem. 

For example, when I input 123. or 123.0, the decimal point and the 0 after the decimal point cannot be displayed on the screen. Only when I continue to enter numbers that are not 0 after the decimal point, and the decimal point does not end with 0, can it be displayed correctly All the numbers I entered. 

I hope the expression to display all the numbers I enter. How can I solve this problem? Thank you once again.

Comment: I just tried your latest method, still the same as before, unable to output（ Input: 123. -> Output: 123 and Input: 123.0 -> Output: 123.0)